# Unhandled promise rejection causing load error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access a JSON object which is an object of objects

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "data":{
      "aqi":95,
      "idx":7024,
      "dominentpol":"pm25",
      "iaqi":{
         "dew":{
            "v":20
         },
         "h":{
            "v":69
         },
         "p":{
            "v":1004.5
         }
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

I want to access the num values present inside the values in "iaqi" object but when I try to access *response.body.iaqi* I get an unhandled promise rejection warning and my localhost server gets stuck while loading. I tried

```
 var aqi = JSON.parse(response_body);
    console.log(aqi);
    const result = Object.values(aqi).map(Object.values).flat();
```

but that didn't give the desired value I required. Any help will be appreciated and please tell me if I'm asking the questions correctly as I joined today only :)

Comment: Would be great if your sample JSON was in text format (i.e. not image) so that others could copy/paste it.

Comment: @antoniom I thought it'd better because it's indented. Here's a sample API call if that helps http://api.waqi.info/feed/delhi/?token=66cc9b64ec97aff8a78266ca41b082edf3e9a65a

Comment: Is the example JSON you included the response body? If so, wouldn't 'iaqi' be `response.body.data.iaqi` (not response.body.iaqi)?

Comment: @SarthakKundra what you actually want to acheive? Create a list containing the values of `iaqi` ? e.g. `[20, 69, 1004.5 ....]` ?

Comment: @terrymorse I saved the api call data in response_body and then parsed it using JSON.parse()

Comment: @antoniom yes, exactly an array of those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `response_body` contains your JSON object. You should try the following:

```js
Object.values(response_body.data.iaqi).map(({v}) => v)
```

OR you can use this one:

```js
var res = []
for (var key in response_body.data.iaqi) {
  res.push(response_body.data.iaqi[key].v)
}
```

if you directly target a browser

Comment: I think that will produce `[ {v: 20}, {v: 69}, {v: 100.5}, ... ]`. Maybe just the number values is better.

Comment: Ooops, yes it will.

Comment: Check this one. Are you targeting directly a browser, or you transpile your code (e.g. through babel?)

Comment: It's returning an empty array. When I'm loggin response_body before parsing it as "aqi" I'm only getting 2 fields in the JSON response i.e. [ { city: 'New York', aqi: 10 } ] . It is only after parsing it is when I log it on the console I get the whole response.

Comment: @SarthakKundra sorry I cannot understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: After the API call when I'm writing console.log(response_body) the output is [ { city: 'New York', aqi: 10 } ] . Therefore, on executing the above code you suggested returned an empty array. Should I replace response_body in that code with the parsed version of it i.e. 'aqi'?

Comment: Here is a sample: 
`fetch("http://api.waqi.info/feed/delhi/?token=66cc9b64ec97aff8a78266ca41b082edf3e9a65a").then(res => res.json()).then(response_body => Object.values(response_body.data.iaqi).map(({v}) => v)).then(console.log)`
that works fine for me!

Comment: Okay. First of all thank you so much for your help! Secondly the fetch call made me realize that there was a problem with my request call parameters. It was really a stupid mistake of not reading the documentation properly. Once again Thanks a lot!